# Add woocommerce product type to body class array

Tags: wordpress, global, woocommerce

I am trying to add Woocommerce product types to the Wordpress body tag class array thats called in header.php with

```
body_class();
```

I have the following function in functions.php but it is not adding the class. If I remove the conditional and just have

```
$classes[] = 'simple-product';
```

Then the class is added. I assume this is to do with an issue getting global values. I am calling in $woocommerce, $post and $product globals as I am not sure which I actually need.

```
//Add Woocommerce body classes
add_filter('body_class','ttm_woocommerce_body_classes');
function ttm_woocommerce_body_classes($classes){
    global $woocommerce, $post, $product;
    if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) $classes[] = 'simple-product';
    return $classes;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `var_dump($product)` to see what (if anything) exists in that object?

According to the [codex](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/), you might have to populate it yourself using `$post->ID`, like so:

```
//Add Woocommerce body classes
add_filter('body_class','ttm_woocommerce_body_classes');
function ttm_woocommerce_body_classes($classes){
    global $post;
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );
    if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) $classes[] = 'simple-product';
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the class name can be more dynamic? Instead of : `if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) $classes[] = 'simple-product';`
 - Rather: `$classes[] = $product->product_type.'-product';`?

Answer (score 0):

In woocommerce page add product_type name in your website body tag. First you need to get this page is a product page.

Using with get_product() you got your page is working with woocommerce functionality.

This is a code to add all product_type name added in body tag.

Add this code into your activate theme folder : functions.php

```
add_filter('body_class','obw_woocommerce_body_classes');
function obw_woocommerce_body_classes( $classes ) {
    global $woocommerce, $post, $product;
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );
    $product_type = $product->product_type;
    if ( $product->product_type == 'external' ) $classes[] = 'external-product';
    if ( $product->product_type == 'grouped' ) $classes[] = 'grouped-product';
    if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) $classes[] = 'simple-product';
    if ( $product->product_type == 'variable' ) $classes[] = 'variable-product';
    return $classes;
}
```